# Neo4j specify fields and column names for CSV export

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm exporting some nodes to a CSV and I want to specify which fields to export, the column (field) names in the header, as well as convert some timestamps to "human-readable" strings. I have previously used a subquery and passed that to the apoc.export.csv.query() function, but I don't see an easy way to do this when I have many different types of nodes. Ideally, I would also like to express the relationships by having the primary keys in a column which is labeled by the relationship type. As an example:

Suppose I have just two node types: Apples and Boxes. There are some Box nodes without a ":HAS" relationship to an Apple node and some with multiple ones. This query gets the values that I want, but doesn't format them in the way I need:

```
MATCH (a:Apple) MATCH (b:B)-[:HAS]->(ab:Apple) 
WITH [a.pk, a.type, a.name, "", ""] AS list1, 
[b.pk, b.type, b.name, ab.pk, b.field1] AS list2 
UNWIND list1 + list2 AS item RETURN item;
```

| item |
| --- |
| 1314757 |
| Red Delicious |
| Fuji |
| "" |
| 7462518 |
| Box1 |
| 9686463 |
| 1472641 |

How I'd like for them to be arranged is like this:

| pk | type | name | HAS Apple (pk) | field1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1314757 | Apple | Braeburn |  |  |
| 7462518 | Apple | Gala |  |  |
| 3010653 | Apple | Fuji |  |  |
| 9686463 | Box | Box1 | 1472641 | fieldval |
| 9686463 | Box | Box2 | 7462518 | fieldval |
| 4726110 | Apple | Red Delicious |  |  |

Is there a way that I can get them in this format using just cypher/apoc? They don't need to be ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Wouldn't OPTIONAL MATCH help you with this? MATCH (a:Apple) OPTIONAL MATCH (b:B)-[:HAS]->(ab:Apple)

Answer (score -1):

You'll find the [UNION clause](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/union/) very helpful here

Something like...

```
MATCH (a:Apple) 
RETURN a.pk AS pk, a.type AS type, a.name AS name, "" AS `HAS Apple (pk)`, "" AS field1
UNION
MATCH (b:B)-[:HAS]->(ab:Apple) 
RETURN b.pk AS pk, b.type AS type, b.name AS name, ab.pk AS `HAS Apple (pk)`, b.field1 AS field1
```